# Change what's new section in PlayStore without releasing an update

Tags: java, android, google-play

Is it possible in any way to update the Whats's New section in the Google Play Store, without making an update for the app?

The thing is that I released an update with 2 languages in the Google Play Store Listing, and then I found out that I made a mistake in the second language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On your app's Console page

1. Go to the `Artifact library` under `Release Management.`
2. Under `Active Artifacts`, click the info icon on the right.
3. Find the `What's new in this version?` section at the bottom of the pop-up.
4. `Edit` the text and click `Submit Update.`

Answer (score 10):

As per the new play console dashboard **(22nd October 2021)**:

> Releases overview --> Latest releases --> select arrow infant of the
> build (it will redirect to production page) --> Scroll down and you can find
> the Edit Release Details button click it.

There you go...! now you can `Edit` the text and `Save`.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it’s possible.

To edit the “what’s new” section in production without generating a new release:

Go to the Google Play console for that particular app - go to the release navigation tab (on the left as of December 7, 2020) and click production. Click on the Release tab and at the bottom (by release notes), click on edit release.

Edit the text with the specific tag for that language: `<en-US>Updated Release Note With Appealing Text<en-US>` then save.